# Remove button deletes in listview but not in objectlist

Tags: c#, list, xaml, uwp

I created an remove button to delete objects in my listview and in my list with objects. I need the 2 lists because I want to safe my kList into an textfile.
Here is my code:

```
   public sealed partial class Kalender : Page
{

    private ObservableCollection<KalenderClass> kList = new ObservableCollection<KalenderClass>();



    public Kalender()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();


    }

    private async void showDialog(string message)
    {
        var window = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Achtung", message);
        await window.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void ButtonStartseite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Telefonbuch));
    }


    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        KalenderClass k1 = new KalenderClass();
        k1.termin = TerminTextbox.Text;
        k1.datum = DatePicker1.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        k1.person = PersonTextbox.Text;
        k1.uhrzeit = myTimePicker.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");  
        kList.Add(k1);
        SaveData(kList);

    }

    private async void SaveData(ObservableCollection<KalenderClass> kList)
    {
        StorageFolder ordner = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile datei = await ordner.CreateFileAsync("Kalender.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(datei, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kList));
        

    }

    private async void ReadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        StorageFolder ordner = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        string path = ordner.Path;
        StorageFile datei = await ordner.GetFileAsync("Kalender.txt");
        string inhalt = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(datei);
        var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<KalenderClass>>(inhalt);

        foreach (var kc in k)
        {
            kList.Add(kc);

        }

    }


    private void TerminTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            kList.RemoveAt(myListView.SelectedIndex);
            
        }
        else
        {
            showDialog("Kein Termin ausgewählt!");
        }
    }

    private void myListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        myListView.ItemsSource = kList;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I can remove the objects in the listview, but it does not delete the objects in my list(kList). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is the definition of ```kList```. ```myListView.SelectedIndex``` will not correspond with the index of your list, especially after some removes. Why do you need to have the items twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove button deletes in listview but not in objectlist

We suggest you use [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) as ListView `ItemSource`, and you just need remove selected item from `ObservableCollection` and the UI interface will update automatically.

```
private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        Items.RemoveAt(MyListView.SelectedIndex);

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
private ObservableCollection<string> Items;

private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "HEE", "DDD", "EEE", "ASDFA" };
    MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;

}
```

**Update**

```
private Task UpdateDataSource()
{
    return Task.Run( async() =>
    {
        StorageFolder ordner = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile datei = await ordner.CreateFileAsync("Kalender.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(datei, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kList));
    });
    
}

private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    
    if (myListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        kList.RemoveAt(myListView.SelectedIndex);
        UpdateDataSource();
    }
    else
    {
        showDialog("Kein Termin ausgewählt!");
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean create an repository?

Comment: Yep, and you could also share a demo with onedrive. please note, you need remove sensitive info before share the demo.

Comment: I run your code, I could delete item when click remove button. but you have not updated the local file content. if we load the data again it will display again. you could try to update the local file content after remove button click.

Comment: thank you very very much! you helped me out a lot. is there any way to create persons and show them in a drop down?

Comment: We suggest you could post new thread for this problem, that could help the people who will visit to it later. for drop down control you check uwp combobox control.